# Laravel - Get data from Many to Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I am building a small application in order to experiment with many-to-many relationships in Laravel 7. This application is about projects and users (many-to-many).

An authenticated user can create new projects. Each project has its own page. On the page of a project, a list is rendered, with the name of each user who is a member to this project, and next to each name, is a button that should remove the specific user/member from that project.

Right now, I'm stuck at the "remove user" function. I do not understand how to get the id of each user on the list, and pass it to the function that will "detach" the many-to-many relationship.

My files are below:

**Migrations**:

Users_Table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->boolean('is_admin')->nullable();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Projects_Table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //primary key
        $table->bigIncrements('id');

        //foreign keys columns
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

        //normal table columns
        $table->string('title')->unique();

        //created_at and updated_at columns
        $table->timestamps();

        //add constraints
        $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    });

}
```

Project_Users_Table (Pivot):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('project_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('project_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Models**:

User.php:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project');
}
```

Project.php:

```
protected $fillable = ['name'];

public function members()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}

public function creator()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

**View**:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($project->members as $member)
    <li>{{$member->name}}

        <!-- if connected user is admin, show "remove user"  button -->
        @if ( Auth::user()->is_admin == 1 )
        <form class="delete_project_form" method="POST" action="{{url('/projects/'.$project->id.'/remove_user/'.$member->id)}}">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <button type="submit" value="Delete">Remove</button>
        </form>
        @endif

    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

**Route**:

web.php:

```
Route::delete('/projects/{project}/remove_user/{member}', 'ProjectController@remove_user');
```

**Controller**:

ProjectController.php:

```
public function remove_user(Project $project)
{
    $user_id = $project->members()->id;
    $project->members()->detach($user_id);
    return redirect('/projects/'.$project->id);
}
```

I know it obviously is not correct, but with this configuration it gives the following error:

> Undefined property:
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$id

> http://localhost/rel_test/public/projects/6/remove_user/2

Can you guys help ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function remove_user(Project $project, User $member)
{
    $project->members()->detach($member->id);
    return redirect('/projects/'.$project->id);
}
```

Since you're passing two parameters in your route. Therefore, you will get one instance of `Project` model and one instance of `User` model. Then just access the relationship and accessing the `detach()` method with `$user->id` will do the work. You can detach multiple users by passing array of ids in `detach()` method, or remove all users from the project by calling `detach()` with no parameters.

[Reference here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Hello, I tried this         $user_id = $project->members()->pluck('id');
                                 $project->members()->detach($user_id);
                                 return redirect('/projects/'.$project->id);
But it removes all users associated with that project, instead of the specific one I'm clicking on.

Comment: Your updated answer works perfectly, thank you ! I had not realized I could pass, more than one parameters into the function, as to create both of the necessary instances like you said.